# Displaying contents of web scrape

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The code below displays all the fields out onto the screen.Is there a way I could get the fields "alongside" each other as they would appear in a database or in a spreadsheet.In the source code the fields track,date,datetime,grade,distance and prizes are found in the resultsBlockHeader div class,and the Fin(finishing position) Greyhound,Trap,SP timeSec and Time Distance are found in Div resultsBlock.I am trying to get them displayed like this
track,date,datetime,grade,distance,prizes,fin,greyhound,trap,sp,timeSec,timeDistance all in one line.Any help appreciated.

```
from urllib import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135754")

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "track"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())

nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "date"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())

 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "datetime"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "grade"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "distance"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "prizes"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "first essential fin"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "essential greyhound"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "trap"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "sp"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "timeSec"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "timeDistance"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "essential trainer"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "first essential comment"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "resultsBlockFooter"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "first essential"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
```

Comment: Store the contents in arrays and then print them later

Comment: PS: _All information published on this website ("the content") is provided for your personal, non-commercial use only. You may make a single copy of information published on this website for your personal, non-commercial use, as a backup. Other than this, you may not copy, modify, re-distribute, transmit, rent, lease or re-license any content contained on this site -- and are granted no further rights or copyright._

Comment: Hi ,the program just gives me one long list,how could I break the list into an array to get the elements to correspond.any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure you are not violating the website's [Terms of Use](http://www.gbgb.org.uk/terms-and-conditions.aspx) - stay on the legal side.

The markup is not very easy to scrape, but what I would do is to iterate over the race headers and for every header, get the desired information about the race. Then, get the sibling results block and extract the rows. Sample code to get you started - extracts the track and the greyhound:

```
from pprint import pprint
from urllib2 import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135754")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

rows = []
for header in soup.find_all("div", class_="resultsBlockHeader"):
    track = header.find("div", class_="track").get_text(strip=True)

    results = header.find_next_sibling("div", class_="resultsBlock").find_all("ul", class_="line1")
    for result in results:
        greyhound = result.find("li", class_="greyhound").get_text(strip=True)

        rows.append({
            "track": track,
            "greyhound": greyhound
        })

pprint(rows)
```

Note that every row you see in the tables is actually represented by 3 lines in the markup:

```
<ul class="contents line1">
   ...
</ul>
<ul class="contents line2">
   ...
</ul>
<ul class="contents line3">
   ...
</ul>
```

The `greyhound` value was inside the first `ul` (with `line1` class), you may need to get the `line2` and `line3` using the `result.find_next_sibling("ul", class="line2")` and `result.find_next_sibling("ul", class="line3")`.