# Scrape html into csv file

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

the code below scrapes data from the following page:
"http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=136005.

It scrapes all of the relevent fields and prints them to screen. However I want to try and print the data in a tabular form into a csv file, to export into a spreadsheet or a database.

In the sites source HTML the track, date, datetime(time of race)grade,distance and prizes are from the div class "resultsBlockheader", and on the web page form the top area of the race card.

The body of the race in the source HTML comes from the div class "resultsBlock",and this includes finishing position(Fin) Greyhound, Trap, SP, Time/Sec and Time distance.

Eventually it will look like this

```
track,date,datetime,grade,distance,prize,fin,greyhound,trap,SP,timeSec,time distance
```

Is this possible or will I have to get it to print onto the screen in tabular form before I can export it to csv.

```
 from urllib import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=136005")
 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "track"})
 for name in nameList:
 List = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "distance"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "prizes"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "first essential fin"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "essential greyhound"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "trap"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "sp"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "timeSec"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "timeDistance"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())

 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "essential trainer"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())

 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "first essential comment"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())

 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "resultsBlockFooter"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())

 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "first essential"})
 for name in nameList:
     print(name. get_text())
```

Comment: This just prints a whole bunch of things each on their own line. If you want a tabular or csv format, you'll need to reformat this whole code

Comment: Hi cricket_007.Thanks for your reply.How would I get the stuff on the screen to print side by side(still very new to all of this) :)

Comment: `print(1,2)` will print on the same line. `print(1)` then `print(2)` will print on a new line. That simple. You must be each value together in a list to print them on one line. Currently you are focused on the columns instead of the rows.

Comment: Hi cricket_007,thanks for the reply again I tried nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "track,grade,distance"})  but got nothing am I doing it right? kind regards Moonsgadow

Comment: That's only correct if there were a div with the class `"track,grade,distance"`. Sidenote: getting multiple classes with beautiful soup is not that straightforward (and there are several questions on this site how to do so)

Comment: Many thanks your advice has been really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why have not you followed the code suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35229724/771848) for your previous question - it actually solves the grouping fields together problem.

Here is a follow up code that dumps `track`, `date` and `greyhound` into csv:

```
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


html = requests.get("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135754").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

rows = []
for header in soup.find_all("div", class_="resultsBlockHeader"):
    track = header.find("div", class_="track").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")
    date = header.find("div", class_="date").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")

    results = header.find_next_sibling("div", class_="resultsBlock").find_all("ul", class_="line1")
    for result in results:
        greyhound = result.find("li", class_="greyhound").get_text(strip=True)

        rows.append({
            "track": track,
            "date": date,
            "greyhound": greyhound
        })


with open("results.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ["track", "date", "greyhound"])

    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Contents of the `results.csv` after running the code:

```
Sheffield,02/02/16,Miss Eastwood
Sheffield,02/02/16,Sapphire Man
Sheffield,02/02/16,Swift Millican
...
Sheffield,02/02/16,Geelo Storm
Sheffield,02/02/16,Reflected Light
Sheffield,02/02/16,Boozed Flame
```

Note that I'm using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) here, but you can stay with `urllib2` if you want.

Comment: Huh. Just noticed how many questions OP has with just this one problem

Comment: Hi alecxe.Many thanks for that code.Ive got all the fields out but can't get the "trainer" "comments" and "first essential",fields out.Any suggestions most welcome :)

Comment: @moonshadow sure, let's avoid resolving follow up problems in comments. Please see if it makes sense to create a separate question if you experience difficulties extracting all of the fields. Thanks.

Comment: hi Alecxe,thanks for that,I will mess around with the code and see if I can solve the prob,but if not I will place up a new question.Many thanks again Moonshadow